# How to use datepicker options within onClose

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

With the [jQuery UI Datepicker Widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField), I want to check if the user left a specific input field blank on blur, if so, then assign the date value to the value of **altField**.  Something like this in my mind...

```js
$(selector).datepicker({
     dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      onClose: function (date) {
         if (!$(this).val()) {
         //at this point, how can I assign my date to be the value of altField: "#hiddenInput"
         } 
         else {
         //...I just carry along and do something with my date...
         }
      }
});
```

Can that be done with the datepicker widget?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bootstrap date picker for solving this type of problem.
Link is given below.
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#

Answer (score 0):

My environment Datetimepicker for Bootstrap 3 version : 4.17.47

```
$("#dateTimePicker").on("dp.hide", function (e) {
  console.log(e.date);
});
```